# Ninject: Binding Identity UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I ran into a problem with my AuthenticationController, for which I use Identity 2.0.
The task is simple, but there's something I cannot understand about Ninject and its bindings.

I want to bind the UserManager to UserStore and the DBContext, but I can't figure out how to do it.
Also, the more important question is in which scope I have to set the bindings for UserManager and UserStore.

Also, I have this method in my AuthenticationController:

```
private void UserValidator(UserManager<User> usermanager)
{
    usermanager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(usermanager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true
    };
}
```

I don't want to create a new UserValidator and to call this method in other method (or in the constructor), but to bind this method with my UserManager when it's created. How can I do this with Ninject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UserManager, UserStore and DBContext are creating dependecy chain so you must type something like that

```
kernel.Bind<IDBContext>().To<DBContext>().InRequestScope(); //It's good practice to use interface
kernel.Bind<DBContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope(); //You can also do it this way
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<User>>().To<UserStore<User>>()
            .InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<IDBContext>());
kernel.Bind<UserManager<User>>().ToSelf()
            .InRequestScope();
```

I think it's better to stay with separate method for UserValidator because it's only used when registering new user.

Comment: This code will create additional DataContext for the UserManager.